# Python-like "as" keyword (for namespacing) in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, module

I was just over [looking at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968410/swig-ruby-overloading-problems).  The first thought that popped to my head was that ruby must have some sort of "as" type keyword like Python's import to help avoid namespace pollution.  I've googled a bit but it seems that it's recommended to [wrap your code in modules](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/require.htm) to avoid namespace problems with ruby.  This seems problematic because what if two modules have conflicting names.

So, any "as" type keywords for ruby's require?

Comment: Choose different module names?

Comment: @Telemachus: it is not your choice when using several 3rd part libraries.

Comment: @Paulo Yup, understood. Let me turn the question around, though. Is this a burning, non-theoretical problem? Are there common, important libraries that use the exact same module and class names and stomp all over each other? It may be the case, but I haven't run into it.

Comment: @Telemachus: I run onto this from time to time and namespace clashes sometimes are very hard to debug. May be it is not practical a problem for you because you are very lucky or work with small codebases.

Comment: What modules have namespace collisions? It would be good for others to know so we could either avoid them, or lobby the developers to adjust their module names to sidestep the problem.

Answer (score 2):

What I always do is start my modules with my company initials for work or my own initials for my personal projects.

```
module JWG_TwitterTools
.
. 
.
end
```

Comment: As @Paulo points out above, this only works if the source code is yours.

Comment: Excellent point. My point is that you can avoid conflicts with your own namespaces, and avoid others having conflicts when they use your code, by applying your own prefix to your libraries and gems. This is a 'best practices' kind of thing that will save you all sorts of grief and if everyone does it then it will cut the potential for conflicts to a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

In ruby 2.0, there will be [`mix` (search for mix)](http://jakescruggs.blogspot.com/2010/08/ruby-kaigi-2010-day-2.html). But now, there is nothing like that... Simply use the full constant path.

Comment: not much detail there, but still interesting.  Thanks for the link.  I'm not sure I know what you mean by "use the constant path", though.